# Inverting SVG image mask

Tags: html, d3.js, svg

In my application, it is more convenient for me to use an image to mask SVG shapes rather than the other way round. (The desired multi-color overlays effects can be achieved either way.) The problem is, when I use a normal (grayscale) image as the mask, the result looks like a negative film. Is there an SVG attribute or clever JS/D3 trick that I can use to tell the browser to invert its masking protocol or am I stuck with converting the images myself (which may end up being less convenient than doing it the other way)?

**Update** Minimal example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Image mask</title>

<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div>
<button>toggle</button>
</div>
</body>
<script>
var width = 194,
 height = 240;
 maskWidth = 30;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
 .attr('height', 500);

var myMask = svg.insert('mask', ':first-child')
 .attr('id', 'image_mask');

var marilyn = myMask.append('image')
 .attr('width', width)
 .attr('height', height)
 .attr('xlink:href', "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Marilyn_Monroe_photo_pose_Seven_Year_Itch.jpg/194px-Marilyn_Monroe_photo_pose_Seven_Year_Itch.jpg");

var positive = svg.append('rect')
 .attr('width',maskWidth)
 .attr('height', height)
 .attr('fill', 'red')
 .attr('mask', 'url(#image_mask)');

var negative = svg.append('rect')
 .attr('x', maskWidth)
 .attr('width', width - maskWidth)
 .attr('height', height)
 .attr('fill', 'green')
 .attr('mask', 'url(#image_mask)');
 
var toggle = false;
d3.select('button').on('click', function() {
 toggle = !toggle;
 positive.transition()
  .attr('height', toggle ? height/2 : height);
});

</script>
```

Comment: You can do great things with SVG Filters - please post your code for adaption

Comment: @MichaelMullany Okay, I've posted a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a `<filter>` to invert the image in your mask.

```html
<svg height="500" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
  <defs>
    <filter id="invert">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
        <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
        <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
      </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter> 
    <mask id="image_mask">
      <image width="194" height="240" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Marilyn_Monroe_photo_pose_Seven_Year_Itch.jpg/194px-Marilyn_Monroe_photo_pose_Seven_Year_Itch.jpg"
             filter="url(#invert)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <rect width="30" height="120" fill="red" mask="url(#image_mask)"/>
  <rect x="30" width="164" height="240" fill="green" mask="url(#image_mask)"/>
</svg>
```